# How to prevent AutoMapper from initializing destination JObject member when source is null

Tags: c#, json.net, automapper, automapper-6

Suppose you have the following classes:

```
public class Source
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public JObject Data { get; set; }
}
```

And you configure AutoMapper using this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(
    cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(
                d => d.Data, 
                c => c.MapFrom(s => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s.Data ?? "")
    }
);
```

When you map a `Source` object with a value for `Data` that results in null json (e.g. a null value, an empty string, or the string "null", all of which result in JsonConvert returning null), the value of `Destination.Data` ends up being set to an empty JObject instead of null.

Is there a way to prevent Automapper from initializing the destination member at all?

There are a few different things you can do but most of them only cover a subset of the cases.  For instance, you can add a condition to the mapping to only apply when `Source.Data` is not null or empty.  But this doesn't work if `Source.Data` is the string "null".

Is there a better way to handle this without needing to add a bunch of special casing conditions on the outside?

*Side Note:* I can get it working by providing a top level mapping between string and JObject.  But that would mean that I have to use the same logic for every case and I ONLY want it to apply to this one property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AllowNullCollections works per profile, but per property, you can try smth like:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
   .ForMember(destination => destination.Data, 
              options => options.AddTransform(data=>data.Count == 0 ? null : data));
```

The thing is, what you resolve gets mapped again and if AllowNullCollections is false, AM will have to create one for you :) See also [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html#preconditions).

Comment: `AllowNullCollections` looks like it'll do what I'm hoping.  I think I'm okay with this being per profile since I can still customize the conversion per-member in this case.

I want to avoid the transform option because data being an empty object is valid and should not be null'd out.